# How to config DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS to accept timestamp?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there anyway to accept timestamp as an input for `DateField` and `DateTimeField` fields by configuring `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS`?

I can convert all my outputs to `timestamp` using :

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = [
   "DATETIME_FORMAT": "%s"
]
```

But it seems having `%s` for inputs does not work:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = [
   "DATETIME_FORMAT": "%s",
   "DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS": ["%s"], 
]
```

It raises this validation error:

```json
{
    "my_field_name": [
        "Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: %s."
    ]
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I can create a custom `DateTimeField` or `DateField` field. But it's really cumbersome as I have to change many fields all over the project. not to mention may of these fields are auto generated by `ModelSerializer` and I don't really like to overwrite them manually.

Answer (score 0):

It uses this [table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime), %S should work but there is no directive with a lowercase s.

Comment: I've seen that table. Uppercase `%S` means second between [00-61]. Sadly it's not related to timestamp.

Comment: You need to use the different options like. For example. 'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"

Comment: Well, As the question suggests... I'm looking for a way to make it accept timestamp.